# docker-compose dynamically see if container was started (or: docker-compose plan?)

Tags: bash, docker-compose

Say I run a docker-compose script that starts `n` containers.

I want to dynamically see if the command started (or re-started) a specific container, as opposed to it already being up.

Is there a way to do this? Or alternately is there a way to ask docker-compose what it's going to do before doing it? (like `terraform plan`?)

The closest idea I had was to `docker-compose ps` right after `docker-compose up` and see the run time of the container, but it's a bit hacky.

Another hacky approach would be to parse the logs, which wouldn't be so bad except I didn't find a clean way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I was in your shoes I'd ask myself why this is necessary, and why this is necessary from a `docker` POV.

Neither `docker` or `docker-compose` is necessarily a release management software but more like a platform / infrastructure software. Arguably `docker-compose` could be considered a deployment software.

Onto your problem, I can't think any framework / library that could sit on top of `docker` / `docker-compose` and help you with this, neither can I find a good solution for you.

The "hacky" ways you suggest might be the best way of doing this (preferably the first). However, I'd still ask myself if this is really necessary? If so, it might be worth moving on to `kubernetes` and using something like `helm`, which gives you *some* measure of what you are looking for.